# Conditionial Concatenation in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

*Short disclaimer: This is my very first question, so please be understanding.*

I'm trying to code a function in Excel VBA that takes a binary number (formatted as a string) that counts the spaces, the 0s, and outputs the *consecutive* amount of 0s (and adds one to it) until the next "1" in that string appears, with "," in between. At the very end of the string, if there's the a "1", the output should look like: "..., 1". I'll try to make a little easier to understand with an example:

```
Strings of length twelve:
101011010101 --> 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1
110000101101 --> 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 1
100010001000 --> 4, 4, 4
```

So far I've managed to make a one-dimensional boolean array that takes the string and splits it into parts of length 1, so to say a "binary array". But I couldn't test it, since I only have half of the function.

```
Function ABSTAND(str As String, size As Integer) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrays(size) As Boolean
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    If Mid(str, i, 1) = "1" Then
        arrays(i) = True
    Else
        arrays(i) = False
    End If
    'Maybe all of this works in a loop?
    'Count consecutive 0s, add one
    'Output the value with ", " (Concatenate numbers with strings, or make the number a string)
    'Count consecutive 0s again
    'and so on...
    'Add conditions for the last value: Don't add a ", " and check if a one is the last character
End Function
```

I know, it looks like I have already figured out the problem and only need to implement it, but I'm new to VBA and don't know that well how it works and how to fix syntax and other problems.

Also, I would like to have a generalized form of my problem, that works with every string length, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, VBA isn't the best language for dealing with arrays. I've written the function as described but it sounds like, from your description, you might want to remove the check for `If Len(arrZeroes(i)) > 0 Then` etc. because it looks like you want to return '1' values in those cases.

Have a play around with the 'Split' function to try get a better feel for it and how it relates to your problem.

```
Function ABSTAND(str As String) As String
    Dim arrZeroes() As String
    Dim arrResult() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'Initialise arrResult dimensions
    ReDim arrResult(1 To 1)

    'Splits your binary number into an array with each element being zero or more 0's
    '(if there are several 1's in a row or a 1 at the start or finish it returns 0-length element for that position)
    arrZeroes = Split(str, "1")

    'Loop through each element in this new array
    For i = LBound(arrZeroes) To UBound(arrZeroes)
        'Sets the top element of the result array to this length + 1 then increments the size (like appending to array)
        arrResult(UBound(arrResult)) = Len(arrZeroes(i)) + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To UBound(arrResult) + 1)
    Next i

    'The last step on the result array incremented its ubound which is still empty so we remove that
    ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To UBound(arrResult) - 1)

    'then return the array joined!
    ABSTAND = Join(arrResult, ", ")
End Function
```

Let me know if anything doesn't make sense!

Edit:
An [array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k7ayc03(v=vs.90).aspx) is basically like an indexed list of elements of a specified data type. The line `Dim arrZeroes() as String` is dimming a dynamic array of string elements. The benefit of using a dynamic array is that you can dynamically change the amount of elements in it using [Redim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement). To get around the lack of an 'append' function, what you have to do is redim the array to make it one element bigger then set this new biggest element to your new value.

```
arrResult(UBound(arrResult)) = Len(arrZeroes(i)) + 1
ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To UBound(arrResult) + 1)
```

That's what these lines are doing. What the `Split` function does is, given a string and a delimiter, cut the string into a load of slices at each occurrence of the delimiter and return the array. For example, `Split("11101101", "0")` returns `{"111", "11", "1"}`. Where there are more than one occurrence of the delimiter in sequence, or the delimiter appears at the beginning or end of the string, it outputs a zero-length element, such as `Split("101101", "1")` returns `{, "0", , "0",}`. What the function is doing is looking at the length of each of these slices (i.e. consecutive digits that are not the delimiter) and outputting them to a new array.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. Could you explain UBound and LBound and Preserve? You're solution seems very neat, but for some reason it outputs "3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3" for example if the input is "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1".

Comment: EDIT: I'm dumb. I chose the wrong column, my bad. It works, but the "1" of "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1" are still missing, and so does for every other input.

Comment: I've changed my answer and the function so it hopefully does what you'd like it to, let me know if anything's still unclear!

Comment: Works like a charm. Just a condition is missing, that the first element isn't taken into account, since that results in a "1" too much in the beginning. I'm trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is just to trim the input if the first element is a 1 with a line like `If Left(str, 1) = "1" Then str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)`.

Comment: Yes, could have done that too. In the meantime I just set the loop for counting the zeroes to start at LBound(arrZeroes) + 1, to avoid the first element to be counted.

Comment: Also, since it is at the beginning of the string, I could just cut that away with everyday excel formatting, e.g. MID(ABSTAND(A1),3,LEN(A1)-3).

Comment: You could indeed! I feel like it's up to you how best to implement it gibven your specifications now you've got it working. Could you mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#` in your code.
It is used for preprocessing directive, and you do not need it.

More about Preprocessing directives:

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/ifthenelse-directive*

In general, try the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print ABSTAND("101011010101", 12)

End Sub

Function ABSTAND(str As String, size As Long) As String


    Dim i               As Long
    Dim arrays()        As Variant
    Dim strResult       As String

    ReDim arrays(size)

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If Mid(str, i, 1) = "1" Then
            arrays(i) = True
        Else
            arrays(i) = False
        End If
        strResult = strResult & arrays(i)
    Next i

    ABSTAND = strResult


End Function
```

It would print something like `TrueFalseTrueFalseTrueTrue...` Then try to build up your solution further.

Just some points:

- Pay attention how the `Array` is created.
- Use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

You can shorten the `ABSTAND` function, to the following:

```
Function ABSTAND(str As String, size As Long) As String


    Dim i               As Long
    Dim arrays()        As Variant
    Dim strResult       As String

    ReDim arrays(size)

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
       arrays(i) = Mid(str, i, 1) = "1"
       strResult = strResult & arrays(i)
    Next i

    ABSTAND = strResult


End Function
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't know that. Thanks for clarification.